# Deduce template parameter's template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

There is a class template `A`, which is taking template class for its template parameter.

```
template <typename T> class A {}
template <typename T> class B {}
int main()
{
    A<B<int>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Can class template `A` deduces its template parameter(`B` int)'s template parameter(int)?

Or is there the other way to solve this problem? For example,

```
template <typename T<typename U>> class A {}
```

Comment: Please see template template parameter syntax: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: You need to make `A` a template template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `A` a template template:

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename Inner> 
class A<T<Inner>> {};
```

Comment: C++17 fixed the fact that only `class` worked after `template<...>`, so `typename` works now too, finally.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class>struct inner{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class...Ts>
struct inner<Z<T, Ts...>>{
  using type=T;
};
template<class Z>
using inner_t=typename inner<Z>::type;
```

and `inner_t<X>` is the first template argument of `X` if it exists, and a substitution failure otherwise.

Comment: `inner_t<X>` is the *sole* template argument of `X`. You'd need `template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class...Rest>
struct inner<Z<T, Rest...>>{
  using type=T;
};` to return the *first* argument.

Comment: @Casey fixed.  Also doesn't work with non-type template arguments (even if they aren't the first).

Answer (score 1):

What you described is a template template:

```
template< template<typename> class T > class A {};
```

note the class before T has to be **class**, not typename.

Comment: C++17 fixed that, so `typename` works now too, finally.